# bedtools single-nucleotide coverage in BED-specified regions for multiple BAMs

Tags: sam, samtools, bed, bedtools, coverage

I have a BED6 (BED + name, score, strand info) file that defines some regions of interest.  I also have a set of BAMs corresponding to different samples.  I would like to obtain output similar to `bedtools genomecov -d -5`, which generates counts of read start positions, but I would like it restricted to regions of interest.

I can do this for individual BAMs and regions by filtering input with `samtools view`, e.g.,

```
bedtools genomecov -d -5 -strand '+' -ibam <(samtools view -b sample1.bam "chr1:12345-23456")
```

but this requires extracting position and strand info from the BED file, and then eventually I have to aggregate all the outputs back into a single file. This ends up being very slow (e.g., hours for ~50 regions of interest X 12 samples).

**Is there a better way to accomplish this?**

Ideally, something along the lines of how `bedtools multicov` works would be great:

```
bedtools multicov -bams /path/to/my/bams/*.bam -bed roi.bed
```

but it doesn't have the `-d` and `-3/5` options to extract single-nucleotide read-end coverage.

Comment: Do you want coverage for each sample separately, or summed up across all samples?

Comment: 50 ~1kb regions (as hinted at in the example) should not take hours to compute. Can you give more meta-information on the regions and BAMs that you are trying to process?

Comment: What's your end goal after making a text file with the values?